# Center (Circle) Div in Footer

Tags: html, css, center

I have a Circle Div in my Footer and want to Center it into the Footer.
At the End there will be 3 Circles in a Row.
[image: How it looks]
My CSS:

```css
.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.90);
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` and `align-items` & `justify-content`  to align it both vertically and horizontally.

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #dedede;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<footer>
<div class="circle"></div>
</footer>
```